# Ftp : limit transfer speed

Tags: c#, ftp

I'm writing a c# app (.Net 4.5) to download files from an ftp server.
I would like, now, to be able to set a maximum download speed.

I can't configure the server, so I will have to do it in the client.
Could anyone explain me how to do so ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the source code for the ftp client, you do this by transfer chunks of data, comparing the transfer rate compared to your desired limit rate and inserting delays if the transfer is going too fast. See [How can I rate limit an upload using TcpClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061612/how-can-i-rate-limit-an-upload-using-tcpclient) for proof of concept code